# How to select only one item in ListView and render it?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I started studying flutter and I'm having a doubt about LsitViewBuilder.

I have this ListView that accesses the JSON data locally by rootBundle, but I would like that when I click on some item it would only open it on the second page.

[image: Like this]

I wanted so much to know how you can select.

My ListView

```
List<dynamic> buy;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    rootBundle.loadString('assets/dados.json').then((jsonData) {
      this.setState(() {
        buy = jsonDecode(jsonData);
      });
    });
  }

........

ListView.builder(
      itemCount: buy?.length ?? 0,
      itemBuilder: (_, index) {
      return buildCardBuy(context, index, buy);
      }
),
```

Comment: Please provide the code of your buildCardBuy() function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap your list view item with the GestureDetector widget, making the Tap event to navigate to another page with the item tapped.

```
ListView.builder(
      itemCount: buy?.length ?? 0,
      itemBuilder: (_, index) {
        return GestureDetector(
            child: buildCardBuy(context, index, buy),
            onTap: () => Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                    // the first refeers to the property on your detail DetailScreen
                    // and the second refers to the current buy being render on
                    // this list view builder
                    builder: (context) => DetailScreen(buy: buy),
                ),
            );
        );
      }
),
```

And in your DetailScreen something like

```
class DetailScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final dynamic buy;

  DetailScreen({Key key, @required this.buy}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
      ),
      body: Container()
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would build a second widget (let's call it ItemWidget) which represents the detail page for the object you want to 'open'.

Then I would add to that ItemWidget a property for the object data that you need to pass.

After that I would implement the logic so that when the list item is clicked, it switches the current list widget with a new ItemWidget and passes to it the properties of the clicked object.